# Using spring @Cacheable with a keyGenerator and unless properties

Tags: java, spring-cache

Using spring-boot 2.4.3
org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.4

I have a @Cacheable method using keyGenerator
It works fine.
I want to add the unless property using a static method, but it does not work.

Sample code of the annotation (which does not invoke the static method

```
@Cacheable(value = CURRENCY_CHANNELS_CACHE, keyGenerator = CURRENCY_CHANNEL_CACHE_KEY_GENERATOR, unless = "#{ T(com.cache.MyCacheKeyGenerator).isQueryNotCacheable(#p0) }")
public List<Item> getQueryForCollection(final QueryBuilder query, final String sort)
```

```
public static boolean com.cache.MyCacheKeyGenerator.isQueryNotCacheable(final QueryBuilder query)
```

is not invoked. I get  error that it is not found.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong SpEL syntax in the `unless` parameter. The correct syntax is:

```
unless = "T(com.cache.MyCacheKeyGenerator).isQueryNotCacheable(#p0)"
```

I have tested the solution here: https://github.com/ygor-sk/stackoverflow/tree/master/q67168108-cacheable-unless-static

Next time, please provide the error you got directly in your question. It must have been quite obvious:

> EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. It works now.
I did not have trace for spring turned on.